# Need guidance publishing Blazor web-app to Azure using Azure Ad for authentication

Tags: c#, azure, azure-active-directory, windows-authentication, blazor-server-side

I have configured Blazor locally so that when it launches the user is promted with a sign in to a azure ad username password. this works fine locally. I have had numerous problems when i publish it to `mydomain.azurewebsites.net` it suddenly fails to work. i get errors from the sign in portal, such as the reply URls are not matching.

I update the reply URl with https://mydomain.azurewebsites.net/signin-oidc and same with the log outs.

I don't understand how it just does not work.. even though it works fine doing it locally(still using Azure AD) so I would of though the application works in the same way.

edit pics :

[Azure Reply URl](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vZOm5.png)

[app settings](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lVWIf.png)

[error after authentication which isn't present with localhost](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2wjEi.png)

update : new error screen (which in azure ad shows a success log in)
[no permission after auth](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZiRhi.png)

UPDATE :: so it looks like when the app is being published it is being published as an enterprise app and not as an app registration, which explains the difference in the client id. does anyone know how to publish this enterprise app with a domain? seeing as its not letting me configure it any other way. thanks

Comment: When you get the sign in prompt, look at the url. It will contain the Redirect URI. Make sure that is what you add to your app registration.

Comment: URL : redirect_uri=https%3A%2F%2Fmydomain.azurewebsites.net%2Fsignin-oidc&response_type=id

Comment: redirect url : https://mydomain.azurewebsites.net/signin-oidc - so it matches but getting the error still?

Comment: Same thing from an incognito window?

Comment: AADSTS50011: The reply URL specified in the request does not match the reply URLs configured for the application: 'application-id - yes same reply after i log in. nb. when i run application locally - works fine and returns me to the blazor application. i dont understand how this is so hard to figure out. driving me crazy!! - is there an added layer of security that needs to be satisfied?

Comment: Are you sure the production configuration is pointing to the right app?

Comment: pretty sure ha! ive changed a couple parts around and made some progress... well progress is a word. anyway giving me 'You do not have permission to view this directory or page.' so i guess this is something

Comment: Do the reply URL specified in the request and the reply URL configured for the application use the same "https" protocol?

Comment: Is it convenient to provide 2 screenshots? 1. A screenshot of Redirect URIs of the application you created in the Azure portal. 2. Screenshot of reply URl configured in the code.

Comment: @CarlZhao added to the post in the links. cheers

Answer (score 1):

I just ran into the same issue. I solved it by use https as protocol for the /signin-oidc endpoint even for localhost. So make sure that you add https://localhost:[PORT_OF_YOUR_LOCAL_APP]/signin-oidc to the redirect-uris.

Comment: im not concerned with localhost, its when its published its not working - as per my question.

Answer (score -1):

This seems to be a common problem, and there is a general solution to the mismatch problem. When you visit the application url (`https://mydomain.azurewebsites.net/`), you will be redirected to the login page. Decode the authorization request URL, you will find redirect_uri, copy the value of redirect_uri and paste it into the azure portal, and try again.

You must ensure that the redirect_uri configured in the Azure portal is exactly the same as the redirect_uri configured in the code.

[image]

Comment: my images show that the request uri is the same as whats in the azure portal and in the app settings - but will try physically decode and update.

Comment: not sure if this means anything but it seems that my url changes... i updated the reply url to /signin-oidc, then the error wanted a reply url of /.auth and so on so i updated it to that, then ran it again to get the error wanting /signin-oidc ...

Comment: @smeca  Try to change the redirect url of Azure portal to: `https://mydomain.azurewebsites.net/.auth/login/aad/callback`.

Comment: yep done that but having no luck. i did notice that it seems that the app is being made automatically when i publish it as an enterprise app, then when i navigate to the Enterprise app, its all set up for localhost. i change the manifest to reflect the live site i tried to publish to, but again same error.